# How should i secure my Web Application(ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am recently having the idea about programming my own web-app, with functions which i will decide later on.
I implemented a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Api=> purpose of the api => authenticate users for my applications.

it has endpoints like => login(here the user will be authenticated with ef core sql etc), refreshtoken,
still pondering about if a "logout" endpoint is useful? is expireson=15min for jwt token enough?

this api will be used for many differenct projects i am planning on.
but i am having problems how i should approach the implenting on my web application.
should i make api calls to my api => get the token => then its just blank. i have no idea how to approach the next step

Can you help me with some tips?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question needs to be more focused as it's unclear exactly what you need. You'll be better off trying something out first. That way you'll be able to ask more precisely regarding the issues you're having. Perhaps as a start you could look at the [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) or how to use [IdentityServer4 for authentication](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/)

Comment: thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

> it has endpoints like => login(here the user will be authenticated
> with ef core sql etc), refreshtoken, still pondering about if a
> "logout" endpoint is useful? is expireson=15min for jwt token enough?

For the logout endpoint and token expired time, it depends on your requirement. Through the logout endpoint, we could clear the current user identifiable information or personal data. For the expired time, you could set it by yourself.

> should i make api calls to my api => get the token => then its just
> blank. i have no idea how to approach the next step

Without any sample code or error message, it is hard to narrow down the problem. So, it is better to post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Generally, when we using JWT authentication, the workflow as below:

1. Client sends a request (which contains the user information, such as: name and password) to server for token
2. Server receives the user information and checking for authorization. If validated success, server generates a JWT token.
3. Client receives the token and stores it somewhere locally.
4. Client sends the token in the future requests.
5. Server gets the token from request header, computes Hash again by using a) Header from token b) payload from token c) secret key which server already has.
6. If ("newly computed hash" = "hash came in token"), token is valid otherwise it is tempered or not valid

After configure your application uses [Asp.net core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and JWT authentication. When a User login, you could send the user information to the server side and check if the current user is valid or not, then generate a JWT token, and on the client side you could store the token in the web storage. After that, when you want to access the resource by passing this token into the authentication HTTP header.

More detail information about using JWT token, please refer to the following article:

[JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

[ASP.NET Core 3.1 API - JWT Authentication with Refresh Tokens](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/25/aspnet-core-3-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens)

Comment: thanks for your comment and the added links.
I recently researched a lot about jwt auth etc.
and its commonly said that jwt as a authentication method is not that good => because the user sends a request for each action to the jwt auth web api and it uses bandwidth etc.
and actions have crud functions it takes more time. 

Is my approach still viable and a good way to structure my applications? or should i rather change my authentication and authorization system.

Comment: Yes, by using JWT Authentication, it contains Pros and Cons. JWTs are like a ticket to an attraction. It contains all the security information a server needs embedded in it. Once the server has handed it out the client just needs to present it whenever it asks for something and the server responds accordingly if it's valid, it is perfectly acceptable and you won't notice any delay with it. So, it's usually applies for the API Authentication or SSO authentication. More details, you could check [this article](https://programming.vip/docs/jwt-vs-session-vs-cookie-for-asp.net-core-web-api.html).

Comment: If you are using the API controller in your Asp.net core Application (which contains the login and logout page), you could directly use the Role-based authorization, Claims-based authorization, Policy-based authorization with Asp.net Core Identity, instead of using JWT authentication. Please refer the following article: [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (click the [slide bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi8g3.png) to check other articles)